# php stops working if user uploads .exe

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm creating an upload system, and whenever the user uploads a file type other than an image extension (e.g. jpg/jpeg/gif), the script breaks.  PHP won't load until I restart `phpstorm`, and my code is really small.  I don't want the user to upload a .exe or any other file extensions.

Here's my code:

```
if (!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
{
    $uploaderrors[] = "Please choose image";
}
$check = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if($check == false)
{
    $uploaderrors[] = "Please choose image";
}
}
```

The script breaks, which ruins the UX.  Is there anyway i can fix this?

Comment: The problem can be related to the file size and not to the extension.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? And is the problem a file size issue rather than a type issue?

Comment: thanks for replying and yes i have checked my error log. it shows no error. thats what i was thinking too. but how can i stop that from happening? everything works good. expect for .webp and .exe and other extensions. what if the user accidentally uploaded one of these?

Comment: my main point is to only allow the user upload image but if he uploads something else i will display error to him not destroy the script

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Javascript (perhaps JQuery) to check that the User uploads the correct File Format before your PHP kicks in... that would be one way of doing it on the Client-Side. Here is an example:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    // ASSUMING THAT YOUR FILE INPUT HAS A CLASS-NAME OF "file_upload"
                    // WE CAN SIMPLY GRAB IT INTO A VARIABLE LIKE SO:
                    var pixFile = $(".file_upload");

                    // NOW, WHEN THE USER INTERACTS WITH THIS FILE-INPUT
                    // WE CAN REACT TO THE CHANGE EVENT...
                    pixFile.on("change", function(evt){
                        var dis_val     = $(this).val();

                        // IF USER TRIES TO UPLOAD ANYTHING OUTSIDE ACCEPTABLE/VALID IMAGE FORMATS
                        // WE INFORM HIM OF OUR PREFERENCES: HERE WE ARE USING ALERT...
                        if( !/(\.)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/.test(dis_val) ){         // ADD OTHER FORMATS YOU WISH TO SUPPORT:  'tiff, psd, pdf'
                            alert("You can only upload image Files (JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP)");    // ADD OTHER FORMATS YOU WISH TO SUPPORT

                            // THEN IMMEDIATELY RESET THE VALUE OF THE UPLOADED FILE TO NULL
                            $(this).val(null);
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            // OTHERWISE: WE KNOW THAT USER UPLOADED THE ACCEPTABLE FILE FORMAT(S)
                            // YOU MAY OR MAY NOT WANT TO REACT TO THIS... THE CHOICE IS YOURS
                            // AND YOU MAY AS WELL JUST DELETE THE ENTIRE ELSE CLAUSE (IF YOU SO WISH)
                        }
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

Comment: but isn't it bad to validate on client side? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @theprogrammer     You are **not** really Validating... you are merely checking that your user uploaded your preferred file-format. In practice, this is preferable otherwise you have to do all this (*file-format control*) on the server-side and then return with an error message if the wrong file-format was uploaded. Both ways work: however, one is quite simpler and most convenient but only you can make the choice which way to go ;-)

Comment: @theprogrammer   As said before, you are not really Validating as this is not even a Validation Script. And yes, the user can't bypass it (theoretically)....

Comment: im sorry for replying again however everything is working correctly and i would like to thank you. expect for the .webp extension. if the user uploads .webp the script like before breaks. but other extensions perfectly works maybe i should rephrase it. not breaks but displays the error connection was reset.